# Find values in dynamic JSON results

Tags: c#, json

I am looking for a script to find the value of $6383.12 for Accounts Receivable (A/R) in this code. There are several values I want to be able to find but I can't seem to figure out how to structure my code to find the values I need.

I have spent time looking through and testing various versions of arrays, ILIst<> and other suggestions but I can't seem to get the final result I am looking for. I can find a single value (for example "Savings") but I don't know how to get the $800 value.

The script I am using is:

```
var root = JToken.Parse(data);

IList<JToken> t = root.SelectTokens("$...ColData[?(@.value == 'Accounts Receivable (A/R)')]").ToList();
foreach (var item in t)
{
Response.Write(item.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

This gives me the Accounts Receivable (A/R) value but not the dollar value associated with it.

Here is the JSON result I am trying to parse through:

```
{

  "Header": {
    "ReportName": "BalanceSheet", 
    "Option": [
      {
        "Name": "AccountingStandard", 
        "Value": "GAAP"
      }, 

      {
        "Name": "NoReportData", 
        "Value": "false"
      }
    ], 
    "DateMacro": "this calendar year-to-date", 
    "ReportBasis": "Accrual", 
    "StartPeriod": "2016-01-01", 
    "Currency": "USD", 
    "EndPeriod": "2016-10-31", 
    "Time": "2016-10-31T09:42:21-07:00", 
    "SummarizeColumnsBy": "Total"
  }, 

  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "ASSETS"
            }, 
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Current Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Bank Accounts"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "35", 
                              "value": "Checking"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "1350.55"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "36", 
                              "value": "Savings"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "800.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "BankAccounts", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Bank Accounts"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "2150.55"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Accounts Receivable"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "84", 
                              "value": "Accounts Receivable (A/R)"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "6383.12"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "AR", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Accounts Receivable"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "6383.12"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Other current assets"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "81", 
                              "value": "Inventory Asset"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "596.25"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "4", 
                              "value": "Undeposited Funds"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "2117.52"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "OtherCurrentAssets", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Other current assets"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "2713.77"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "CurrentAssets", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Current Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "11247.44"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Fixed Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "id": "37", 
                          "value": "Truck"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "38", 
                              "value": "Original Cost"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "13495.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Truck"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "13495.00"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "FixedAssets", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Fixed Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "13495.00"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "Section", 
        "group": "TotalAssets", 
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "TOTAL ASSETS"
            }, 
            {
              "value": "24742.44"
            }
          ]
        }
      }, 
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "LIABILITIES AND EQUITY"
            }, 
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Liabilities"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Current Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Accounts Payable"
                              },
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "33", 
                                    "value": "Accounts Payable (A/P)"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "1984.17"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "AP", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Accounts Payable"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": "1984.17"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }, 
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Credit Cards"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "41", 
                                    "value": "Mastercard"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "157.72"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "CreditCards", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Credit Cards"
                              },
                              {
                                "value": "157.72"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }, 
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Other Current Liabilities"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "89", 
                                    "value": "Arizona Dept. of Revenue Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "4.55"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "90", 
                                    "value": "Board of Equalization Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "401.98"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "43", 
                                    "value": "Loan Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "4000.00"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "OtherCurrentLiabilities", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Other Current Liabilities"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": "4406.53"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "CurrentLiabilities", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Current Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "6548.42"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Long-Term Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "44", 
                              "value": "Notes Payable"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "25000.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "LongTermLiabilities", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Long-Term Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "25000.00"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "Liabilities", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Liabilities"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "31548.42"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Equity"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "id": "34", 
                        "value": "Opening Balance Equity"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "-9337.50"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "id": "2", 
                        "value": "Retained Earnings"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "91.25"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Net Income"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "2440.27"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data", 
                    "group": "NetIncome"
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "Equity", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Equity"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "-6805.98"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "Section", 
        "group": "TotalLiabilitiesAndEquity", 
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "TOTAL LIABILITIES AND EQUITY"
            }, 
            {
              "value": "24742.44"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "Columns": {
    "Column": [
      {
        "ColType": "Account", 
        "ColTitle": "", 
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey", 
            "Value": "account"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "ColType": "Money", 
        "ColTitle": "Total", 
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey", 
            "Value": "total"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
        var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
        var jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
        var reader = jToken.CreateReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var value = reader.Value;
            if (value != null && value.ToString() == "Accounts Receivable (A/R)")
            {
                var test = jToken.SelectToken(reader.Path.Replace("[0].value", "[1].value"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked perfect. What is "[0].value", "[1].value" doing for my own reference? What is the logic?

Comment: @D-G the value is always on the second dictionary. The first dictionary is for the label you are searching for. Thats why once you determine where is path is it is always on the second dictionary if you want to get the value or the amount. Glad it helps you.

Comment: I mean not dictionary but on array. 

Answer (score 0):

If it's not doable to write json path which selects proper tokens you could try using Parent property and Children method.

```
foreach (var item in t)
        {
            var valueToken = item.Parent.Children().ElementAt(1);

            Response.Write(valueToken.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");
        }
```